# When I create list A and then separate it with list C, then I cannot add list D

Tags: python, list

In the following code, when I create list A and then separate it with list C, then I cannot add list D

```
a=11
b=21
A=[]
n=10

for y in range (11,b):
    for x in range (1,a):
        A.append(x*y)

for i in range (a-1):
    C=A[i*n:(i+1)*n]
    D=A[i*n]
    print(D+C)
```

Comment: Where is the question, the above is just a bunch of code.

Comment: `D` is not a list. Did you mean to write `D=A[:i*n]` or something?

Comment: It is my first time to ask my question here. I wrote my problem in the title.

Comment: how can I make it list and then add to the list C as a first element

Comment: Questions where the text is just in the title are not likely to have enough information to be useful for future readers, which is why this question was put on hold. If you can improve it, that would be appreciated, and perhaps it can be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see:

C is a list, while D is an element from list A unless A is a list of lists.

You can do

```
D=[A[i*n]]
```

That will make D a list of single element

Comment: thanks a lot ....now, I learnt how I can change the int to the list

Comment: Cool. If it helps, feel free to rank up the post.